# Web App Drops Non-Session Cookies On First Offline App Load

Tags: c#, javascript, ipad, cookies, iphone-standalone-web-app

I've created a  web app that utilizes cookies for storing app state to allow for the app being opened multiple times and a user's session to persist across it. I'm using a cache.manifest to allow offline access of the app.

I am able to add cookies to the browser from the app without any issue. Note that they are not session cookies, but all expire at least 1 year from the time of creation. The cookies are created in 2 ways:
1. Using https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
2. Using Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie); in C# server code

I am able to confirm through after connecting my iPad to developer tools that the cookies are visible and can be utilized in the app's JavaScript after they have been added to the app.

However, once I switch the iPad into Airplane Mode and re-open the app, all of the cookies are nowhere to be found. They are not visible in the developer tools, as well as in the requests. I know that the manifest is working correctly because the javaScript code redirects me to the login screen where an image is correctly displayed.

One other piece of info might help... If I go back online, re-login to the application so that the cookies are added again (though both methods), and then back offline, the cookies remain attached to the browser.

I'm going to go down the route of converting as much as I can to use LocalStorage but was hoping that someone would be able to clarify what is going on here for me.